# SQL query select from 3 table Many-to-Many

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

table `post`:

```
   post_id    |    title
---------------------------------
      1       |   post number 1
      2       |   post number 2
      3       |   post number 3
```

table `categories`:

```
   category_id   |   cate_name
--------------------------------
        1        |     video
        2        |     review
        3        |     gameplay
```

table `post_categories`:

```
 post_id   |   category_id
---------------------------------
   1       |      1
   2       |      2
   3       |      3
   2       |      1
   3       |      2
   1       |      3
```

How can do I select `post's title` and `category's name`? Result should look like this:

```
        title       |   cate_name
-----------------------------------------
   post number 1    |   video, gameplay 
   post number 2    |   video, review
   post number 3    |   review, gameplay
```

Is this possible?

Comment: `JOIN` & `GROUP_CONCAT` should help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok try this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  post.title as title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cate_name) as cate_name
  FROM post
    LEFT JOIN post_categories
        ON post_categories.post_id = post.post_id
    LEFT JOIN categories
        ON post_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
  GROUP BY post.post_id;
```

Comment: Thanks! But result just have only 1 row

Comment: @OmegaP ok.  Give me a couple min and I'll sort it out.

Comment: I was found correct answer, but I'll next your answer. I removed `DISTINCT` of `SELECT` and add GROUP BY `post_id`

Comment: Yea I forgot that stuff, it is in there now.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It very helpful for me.

Comment: Sorry, I have a question. If i have `post number 4`, and it hasn't category. Follow your code: `post number 4` not show, but i want show `post number 4` in result with field `cate_name` is `Null`

Answer (score 0):

Please try following sql query.Then you get complete rows.

```
select post.title,GROUP_CONCAT(categories.cate_name SEPARATOR ', ') from  post_categories join post ON post.post_id=post_categories.post_id join categories ON categories.category_id=post_categories.category_id group by post.title
```